# Unable to insert elements in the Xml of an addin

Tags: excel, xml, element, office-addins, appendchild

I am unable to insert "Runtimes" and "Enabled" elements in the Xml of a native Excel web complement generated from Visual Studio. System raises an "unvalid child element" error. I did try it on 4 different windows and visual studio configurations with 2 different lists of app installed. Langage used is french (it shouldn't be an issue)

I am short of hypothesis to explain this issue. Is any one using those elements? Please notify if you don't reproduce the problem.

My Xml for "Runtimes" :
[system raises "Unvalid element in host"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNvkg.png)

My XML for "Enabled" :
[system raises "Unvalid element in control"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7t4O.png)

system raises "Unvalid element in control"

Tags

Comment: @RickKirkham. How does it happen that this question was not published although it seems to fulfill all constraints ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by Rick Kirkham. See my question "unable to enable/disable a control" on may 7th